# Querying information from database using php/SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

[image: database columns]

I want to select data from a table using those two columns. I'm i trying to do is select the table where **month** is between *February and August* and **year** between *2003 and 2005* including the month of january for 2004 and 2005. I have tried this:
`

```
$number = range(3, 8);  

foreach($number as $key=> $value):
                    $where .= " Month ='$value' AND Year BETWEEN '2003' AND '2005' or " ;                   
        endforeach;
if(strlen(trim($where)) > 0)

    $where = substr(trim($where), 0, -2);`
$query = "SELECT * FROM myTable $where";
```

**which return the following query**

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE Month ='2' AND Year BETWEEN '2003' AND '2005' or Month ='3' AND Year BETWEEN '2003' AND '2005' or Month ='4' AND Year BETWEEN '2003' AND '2005' or Month ='5' AND Year BETWEEN '2003' AND '2005' or Month ='6' AND Year BETWEEN '2003' AND '2005' or Month ='7' AND Year BETWEEN '2003' AND '2005' or Month ='8' AND Year BETWEEN '2003' AND '2005'
```

But the problem with my query is it is not selecting january of  2004 and 2005.
Any one with an idea of how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM myTable 
WHERE ( Month >=2 AND Month <=8 AND year BETWEEN 2003 AND 2005) OR (Month=1 AND (year=2004 OR year=2005))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot  for marking as correct. Can you please upvote too?

Answer (score 0):

Change your query like below..

```
SELECT * FROM myTable 
WHERE 
(Month ='2' AND Year BETWEEN '2003' AND '2005') 
or
( Month ='3' AND Year BETWEEN '2003' AND '2005')....
```

The [precedence of operators determines the order of evaluation of terms](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/operator-precedence.html) in an expression. To override this order and group terms explicitly, use parentheses